# Should 'using' directives be inside or outside the namespace in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, stylecop, code-organization

I have been running [StyleCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StyleCop) over some C# code, and it keeps reporting that my `using` directives should be inside the namespace.

Is there a technical reason for putting the `using` directives inside instead of outside the namespace?

Comment: Sometimes it makes difference where you put usings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292535/linq-to-sql-designer-bug

Comment: Just for reference, there are implications beyond just the question of multiple classes per file, so if you're new to this question, please keep reading.

Comment: Terminology: Those are not `using` _statements_; they are `using` ___directives___. A `using` statement, on the other hand, is a language structure that occurs along with other statements inside a method body etc. As an example, `using (var e = s.GetEnumerator()) { /* ... */ }` is a statement that is loosely the same as `var e = s.GetEnumerator(); try { /* ... */ } finally { if (e != null) { e.Dispose(); } }`.

Comment: If this was not mentioned already by anyone, actually Microsoft too recommends putting `using` statements inside the `namespace` declarations, in their [internal coding guidlines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2005/01/26/internal-coding-guidelines/)

Comment: Putting them outside the namespace assists in detecting naming conflicts sooner rather than later, if used as a convention in a team, as it would be consistently at the same level as all other using directives.

Comment: And 5 years later, the [default StyleCop has you put them **outside** the `namespace` declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0065)

Answer (score 2396, accepted):

There is actually a (subtle) difference between the two. Imagine you have the following code in File1.cs:

```
// File1.cs
using System;
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    class Foo
    {
        static void Bar()
        {
            double d = Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

Now imagine that someone adds another file (File2.cs) to the project that looks like this:

```
// File2.cs
namespace Outer
{
    class Math
    {
    }
}
```

The compiler searches `Outer` before looking at those `using` directives outside the namespace, so it finds `Outer.Math` instead of `System.Math`. Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately?), `Outer.Math` has no `PI` member, so File1 is now broken.

This changes if you put the `using` inside your namespace declaration, as follows:

```
// File1b.cs
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    using System;
    class Foo
    {
        static void Bar()
        {
            double d = Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler searches `System` before searching `Outer`, finds `System.Math`, and all is well.

Some would argue that `Math` might be a bad name for a user-defined class, since there's already one in `System`; the point here is just that there *is* a difference, and it affects the maintainability of your code.

It's also interesting to note what happens if `Foo` is in namespace `Outer`, rather than `Outer.Inner`. In that case, adding `Outer.Math` in File2 breaks File1 regardless of where the `using` goes. This implies that the compiler searches the innermost enclosing namespace before it looks at any `using` directive.

Comment: [Fundamentals - program-structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements#using-directives) states for [tag:c#-9.0] [tag:.net-6.0] that  `using directives must come first in the file`. Does anyone know what this means for the example above?

Comment: @surfmuggle I believe that your link refers specifically to console apps without a main method, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @surfmuggle That is specifically referring to top-level statements. When using top-level statements then a namespace must come after all other top-level statements in the file, of course you are also then allowed to add using directives inside the namespace.

Answer (score 581):

This thread already has some great answers, but I feel I can bring a little more detail with this additional answer.

First, remember that a namespace declaration with periods, like:

```
namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities
{
    ...
}
```

is entirely equivalent to:

```
namespace MyCorp
{
    namespace TheProduct
    {
        namespace SomeModule
        {
            namespace Utilities
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to, you could put `using` directives on all of these levels. (Of course, we want to have `using`s in only one place, but it would be legal according to the language.)

The rule for resolving which type is implied, can be loosely stated like this: **First search the inner-most "scope" for a match, if nothing is found there go out one level to the next scope and search there, and so on**, until a match is found. If at some level more than one match is found, if one of the types are from the current assembly, pick that one and issue a compiler warning. Otherwise, give up (compile-time error).

Now, let's be explicit about what this means in a concrete example with the two major conventions.

**(1) With usings outside:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
//using MyCorp.TheProduct;  <-- uncommenting this would change nothing
using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule;
using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration;
using ThirdParty;

namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities
{
    class C
    {
        Ambiguous a;
    }
}
```

In the above case, to find out what type `Ambiguous` is, the search goes in this order:

1. Nested types inside `C` (including inherited nested types)
2. Types in the current namespace `MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities`
3. Types in namespace `MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule`
4. Types in `MyCorp.TheProduct`
5. Types in `MyCorp`
6. Types in the *null* namespace (the global namespace)
7. Types in `System`, `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.Linq`, `MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule`, `MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration`, and `ThirdParty`

The other convention:

**(2) With usings inside:**

```
namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using MyCorp.TheProduct;                           // MyCorp can be left out; this using is NOT redundant
    using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule;               // MyCorp.TheProduct can be left out
    using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration;   // MyCorp.TheProduct can be left out
    using ThirdParty;

    class C
    {
        Ambiguous a;
    }
}
```

Now, search for the type `Ambiguous` goes in this order:

1. Nested types inside `C` (including inherited nested types)
2. Types in the current namespace `MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities`
3. Types in `System`, `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.Linq`, `MyCorp.TheProduct`, `MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule`, `MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration`, and `ThirdParty`
4. Types in namespace `MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule`
5. Types in `MyCorp`
6. Types in the *null* namespace (the global namespace)

(Note that `MyCorp.TheProduct` was a part of "3." and was therefore not needed between "4." and "5.".)

**Concluding remarks**

No matter if you put the usings inside or outside the namespace declaration, there's always the possibility that someone later adds a new type with identical name to one of the namespaces which have higher priority.

Also, if a nested namespace has the same name as a type, it can cause problems.

It is always dangerous to move the usings from one location to another because the search hierarchy changes, and another type may be found. Therefore, choose one convention and stick to it, so that you won't have to ever move usings.

Visual Studio's templates, by default, put the usings *outside* of the namespace (for example if you make VS generate a new class in a new file).

One (tiny) advantage of having usings *outside* is that you can then utilize the using directives for a global attribute, for example `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]` instead of `[assembly: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]`.

---

Addition inspired by [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180703/): Suppose in the above example that the namespace `MyCorp.TheProduct.System` happened to exist, even though we have no use for it in our file. Then with usings outside, it would not change anything. But with usings *inside*, you would have to use the `global` alias, like this:

```
namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities
{
    using global::System;  // avoids 'MyCorp.TheProduct.System' which also exists
    using global::System.Collections.Generic;
    // etc.
}
```

---

**Update about file-scoped namespace declarations**

Since C# 10.0 (from 2021), you can avoid indentation and use either (convention 1, usings outside):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule;
using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration;
using ThirdParty;

namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities;

class C
{
    Ambiguous a;
}
```

or (convention 2, usings inside):

```
namespace MyCorp.TheProduct.SomeModule.Utilities;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MyCorp.TheProduct;
using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule;
using MyCorp.TheProduct.OtherModule.Integration;
using ThirdParty;

class C
{
    Ambiguous a;
}
```

But the same considerations as before apply.

Comment: Just had a case where a class library I inherited had some classes in the global/null namespace.  One of the class names was the same as a class name inside a namespace I was using.  The 'using's were outside the namespace definition.  I couldn't figure out why it would always pick up the definition of the global class.  By chance, put the namespace outside - and it picked up the class I needed.  Your answer explains why.  With the namespace outside, null/globals get picked up last.  To me, this is the proper/expected behavior.

Comment: @PaulEvans Your case is also an example why one should never put anything in the global namespace, especially not anything public. The library you used violated that.

Answer (score 215):

Putting it inside the namespaces makes the declarations local to that namespace for the file (in case you have multiple namespaces in the file) but if you only have one namespace per file then it doesn't make much of a difference whether they go outside or inside the namespace.

```
using ThisNamespace.IsImported.InAllNamespaces.Here;

namespace Namespace1
{ 
   using ThisNamespace.IsImported.InNamespace1.AndNamespace2;

   namespace Namespace2
   { 
      using ThisNamespace.IsImported.InJustNamespace2;
   }       
}

namespace Namespace3
{ 
   using ThisNamespace.IsImported.InJustNamespace3;
}
```

Comment: namespaces provide a logical separation, not a physical (file) one.

Comment: It's not quite true that there is no difference; `using` directives within `namespace` blocks can refer to relative namespaces based on the enclosing `namespace` block.

Comment: yeah I know. we established that in this question's accepted answer five years ago.

Answer (score 63):

According to [Hanselman - Using Directive and Assembly Loading...](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDoNamespaceUsingDirectivesAffectAssemblyLoading.aspx) and other such articles there is technically no difference.

My preference is to put them outside of namespaces.

Comment: @Chris M: uh... the link posted in the answer indicates there's _no_ benefit to in vs. out, actually showing an example that falsifies the claim made in the link you posted...

Comment: Aye I didn't fully read the thread but bought in when the MVPs said it was right. A guy disproves it, explains it and shows his code further down... "The IL that the C# compiler generates is the same in either case. In 
fact the C# compiler generates precisely nothing corresponding to each using directive. Using directives are purely a C#ism, and they have no meaning to .NET itself. (Not true for using statements but those are something quite different.)" http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/msg/781738deb0a15c46

Comment: Please include a summary of the link. **When** the link is broken (because it *will* happen, given enough time), suddenly an answer with 32 upvotes is only worth `My style is to put them outside the namespaces.` - barely an answer at all.

Comment: The claim here is simply wrong ... there is a technical difference and your own citation says so ... in fact, that's what it's all about. Please delete this mistaken answer ... there are far better, and accurate, ones.

Comment: OP has stated "_there is technically no difference_" in their answer and they are correct - from a _technical perspective_ there is _no difference_.  Claiming that this is a mistaken answer is plain wrong

Comment: this is a completely miss-leading answer. the "technically no difference" from the link is not talking about the question posted here.  It's about lazy loading.  In terms of how the namespaces are searched there is a difference; edge case or not.

Answer (score 61):

According the to StyleCop Documentation:

SA1200: UsingDirectivesMustBePlacedWithinNamespace

Cause 
A C# using directive is placed outside of a namespace element.

Rule Description 
A violation of this rule occurs when a using directive or a using-alias directive is placed outside of a namespace element, unless the file does not contain any namespace elements.

For example, the following code would result in two violations of this rule.

```
using System;
using Guid = System.Guid;

namespace Microsoft.Sample
{
    public class Program
    {
    }
}
```

The following code, however, would not result in any violations of this rule:

```
namespace Microsoft.Sample
{
    using System;
    using Guid = System.Guid;

    public class Program
    {
    }
}
```

This code will compile cleanly, without any compiler errors. However, it is unclear which version of the Guid type is being allocated. If the using directive is moved inside of the namespace, as shown below, a compiler error will occur:

```
namespace Microsoft.Sample
{
    using Guid = System.Guid;
    public class Guid
    {
        public Guid(string s)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Guid g = new Guid("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

The code fails on the following compiler error, found on the line containing `Guid g = new Guid("hello");`

CS0576: Namespace 'Microsoft.Sample' contains a definition conflicting with alias 'Guid'

The code creates an alias to the System.Guid type called Guid, and also creates its own type called Guid with a matching constructor interface. Later, the code creates an instance of the type Guid. To create this instance, the compiler must choose between the two different definitions of Guid. When the using-alias directive is placed outside of the namespace element, the compiler will choose the local definition of Guid defined within the local namespace, and completely ignore the using-alias directive defined outside of the namespace. This, unfortunately, is not obvious when reading the code.

When the using-alias directive is positioned within the namespace, however, the compiler has to choose between two different, conflicting Guid types both defined within the same namespace. Both of these types provide a matching constructor. The compiler is unable to make a decision, so it flags the compiler error.

Placing the using-alias directive outside of the namespace is a bad practice because it can lead to confusion in situations such as this, where it is not obvious which version of the type is actually being used. This can potentially lead to a bug which might be difficult to diagnose.

Placing using-alias directives within the namespace element eliminates this as a source of bugs.

2. Multiple Namespaces

Placing multiple namespace elements within a single file is generally a bad idea, but if and when this is done, it is a good idea to place all using directives within each of the namespace elements, rather than globally at the top of the file. This will scope the namespaces tightly, and will also help to avoid the kind of behavior described above.

It is important to note that when code has been written with using directives placed outside of the namespace, care should be taken when moving these directives within the namespace, to ensure that this is not changing the semantics of the code. As explained above, placing using-alias directives within the namespace element allows the compiler to choose between conflicting types in ways that will not happen when the directives are placed outside of the namespace.

How to Fix Violations
To fix a violation of this rule, move all using directives and using-alias directives within the namespace element.

Comment: @Jared - as I noted in my answer, my prefered workaround / solution is to only ever have one class per file. I think that this is a fairly common convention.

Comment: Indeed, it's also a StyleCop rule!  
SA1402: A C# document may only contain a single class at the root level unless all of the classes are partial and are of the same type.  
Showcasing one rule by breaking another just drips with wrong sauce.

Comment: Upvoted for being the first answer to actually cover it from the StyleCop perspective. Personally I like the visual feel of `using`s outside the namespace. Inner `using`s looks so ugly to me. :)

Comment: Finally a good answer to the question. And benPearce's comment is irrelevant ... this has nothing to do with the number of classes in the file.

Answer (score 39):

There is an issue with placing using statements inside the namespace when you wish to use aliases. The alias doesn't benefit from the earlier `using` statements and has to be fully qualified.

Consider:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System;
    using MyAlias = System.DateTime;

    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

versus:

```
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    using MyAlias = DateTime;

    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

This can be particularly pronounced if you have a long-winded alias such as the following (which is how I found the problem):

```
using MyAlias = Tuple<Expression<Func<DateTime, object>>, Expression<Func<TimeSpan, object>>>;
```

With `using` statements inside the namespace, it suddenly becomes:

```
using MyAlias = System.Tuple<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.DateTime, object>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.TimeSpan, object>>>;
```

Not pretty.

Comment: Your `class` needs a name (identifier). You cannot have a `using` directive inside a class as you indicate. It must be on a namespace level, for example outside the outermost `namespace`, or just inside the innermost `namespace` (but not inside a class/interface/etc.).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks. I misplaced the `using` directives mistakenly. I've edited it to how I intended it to be. Thanks for pointing out. The reasoning is still the same, though.

Answer (score 16):

One wrinkle I ran into (that isn't covered in other answers):

Suppose you have these namespaces:

- Something.Other
- Parent.Something.Other

When you use `using Something.Other` *outside* of a `namespace Parent`, it refers to the first one (Something.Other).

However if you use it *inside* of that namespace declaration, it refers to the second one (Parent.Something.Other)!

There is a simple solution: add the "`global::`" prefix: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/how-to-use-the-global-namespace-alias)

```
namespace Parent
{
   using global::Something.Other;
   // etc
}
```

Comment: Good point! I bumped into the related issue working with RazorGenerator. Unfortunately, seems like it does not understand 'global::' and converts it to `using global;' :( It's a pity I cannot select if 'using' needs to be generated inside or outside of 'namespace'...

Answer (score 12):

Another subtlety that I don't believe has been covered by the other answers is for when you have a class and namespace with the same name.

When you have the import inside the namespace then it will find the class. If the import is outside the namespace then the import will be ignored and the class and namespace have to be fully qualified.

```
//file1.cs
namespace Foo
{
    class Foo
    {
    }
}

//file2.cs
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    using Foo;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //This will allow you to use the class
            Foo test = new Foo();
        }
    }
}

//file3.cs
using Foo; //Unused and redundant    
namespace Bar
{
    class Bar
    {
        Bar()
        {
            Foo.Foo test = new Foo.Foo();
            Foo test = new Foo(); //will give you an error that a namespace is being used like a class.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is explained by the search order I give in my answer above. In `file3.cs` you have to say `Foo.Foo`, as you say. The `using` directive there is useless. However, in `file2.cs`, you have no access to the namespace. Like if you say `Foo.DeeperNamespace.SomeClass` in `Main` method, it will search only inside `Foo` class, not inside the `Foo` namespace. So you will need `global::Foo.DeeperNamespace` there. In any case, all guides advise _against_ using the same name for a namespace and a type.

Answer (score 9):

As Jeppe Stig Nielsen [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16092975/2707705), this thread already has great answers, but I thought this rather obvious subtlety was worth mentioning too.

`using` directives specified inside namespaces can make for shorter code since they don't need to be fully qualified as when they're specified on the outside.

The following example works because the types `Foo` and `Bar` are both in the same global namespace, `Outer`.

Presume the code file *Foo.cs*:

```
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    class Foo { }
}
```

And *Bar.cs*:

```
namespace Outer
{
    using Outer.Inner;

    class Bar
    {
        public Foo foo;
    }
}
```

That may omit the outer namespace in the `using` directive, for short:

```
namespace Outer
{
    using Inner;

    class Bar
    {
        public Foo foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is true that you "may omit the outer namespace," but it doesn't mean you should. To me, this is another argument as to why using directives (other than aliases as in @Neo's answer) should go outside the namespace, to force fully-qualified namespace names.

Answer (score 6):

The technical reasons are discussed in the answers and I think that it comes to the personal preferences in the end since the difference is not that *big* and there are tradeoffs for both of them. Visual Studio's default template for creating `.cs` files use `using` directives outside of namespaces e.g.

One can adjust stylecop to check `using` directives outside of namespaces through adding `stylecop.json` file in the root of the project file with the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
    "orderingRules": {
      "usingDirectivesPlacement": "outsideNamespace"
    }
  }
}
```

You can create this config file in solution level and add it to your projects as 'Existing Link File' to share the config across all of your projects too.

Answer (score 6):

###### Not already mentioned:

Placing the `using` directives ***inside*** the namespace declaration is an application of the well-known best programming practice of ***declaring everything in the smallest scope possible***.

If best programming practices are second nature to you, then you do things like that automatically.

This might be the best reason for putting your using directives inside the namespace declaration, regardless of (borderline) technical (borderline) merits mentioned elsewhere;  It's as simple as that.

---

###### Already mentioned but perhaps better illustrated:

Placing `using` directives ***inside*** the namespace avoids unnecessary repetition and makes our declarations more terse.

This is unnecessarily terse:

```
using Com.Acme.Products.Traps.RoadRunnerTraps;
namespace Com.Acme.Products.Traps {
```

This is sweet and to the point:

```
namespace Com.Acme.Products.Traps { 
using RoadRunnerTraps;
```

Answer (score 4):

As a rule, external `using` directives (System and Microsoft namespaces for example) should be placed *outside* the `namespace` directive.  They are defaults that should be applied in all cases **unless otherwise specified**.  This should include any of your own organization's internal libraries that are not part of the current project, or `using` directives that reference other primary namespaces in the same project.  Any `using` directives that reference other modules in the current project and namespace should be placed **inside** the `namespace` directive.  This serves two specific functions:

- It provides a visual distinction between local modules and 'other' modules, meaning everything else.
- It scopes the local directives to be applied **preferentially** over global directives.

The latter reason is significant.  It means that it's harder to introduce an ambiguous reference issue that can be introduced by a change no more significant than **refactoring code**.  That is to say, you move a method from one file to another and suddenly a bug shows up that wasn't there before.  Colloquially, a 'heisenbug' - historically fiendishly difficult to track down.

Comment: @jwdonahue: When I was invited to join the C# feature design team I had been a professional compiler developer and language designer for almost a decade and I was *by far* the most junior person in the room. The C# design team will certainly take great ideas that come from interns; the notion that there is a dearth of experience in designing, evaluating, specifying and implementing language features on the C# design team is not factual.

Comment: Similarly, this answer opens with the bizarre and utterly contrary to fact supposition that the authors of the frameworks design guidelines are just making a list of their preferences. Nothing could be further from the truth. We vigorously debated those guidelines in a room full of experts and stakeholders; they were the product of careful consideration of the needs of professional developers.

Comment: @EricLippert, in hind-sight, it was a silly thought I shouldn't have voiced. Apologies.

Comment: I think this is an otherwise solid answer which is diminished (and probably downvoted because of) the first and last paragraphs. I suggest just removing the first and last paragraphs.

Comment: @andrewf  Nice to see a response that offers some solid ideas to improve the post.  My thanks.  Although I don't quite see the issue with the *last* paragraph...

Answer (score 3):

While most answers lean towards placing `using` directives inside the `namespace` declaration, it is interesting to see that Microsoft's recommendation in [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) says otherwise:

> **Place the using directives outside the namespace declaration**
>
> When a using directive is outside a namespace declaration, that
> imported namespace is its fully qualified name. That's more clear.
> When the using directive is inside the namespace, it could be either
> relative to that namespace or it's fully qualified name. That's
> ambiguous.

In [this other post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/internal-coding-guidelines) however, they prescribe the opposite:

> Using statements should be inside the namespace declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.
According to StyleCop, inside.
According to Microsoft, outside.

(Just wanted a real short answer, I read the entire thread, but not everyone has time for that)

Answer (score -7):

It is a better practice if those **default** using i.e. "*references*" used in your source solution should be outside the namespaces and those that are **"new added reference"** is a good practice is you should put it inside the namespace. This is to distinguish what references are being added.

Comment: No, actually that is a bad idea. You should not base the location between locally scoped and globally scoped of using directives on the fact that they are newly added or not. Instead, it is good practice to alphabetize them, except for BCL references, which should go on top.