# Can't compile with 'using' inside the namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, code-formatting

I have the following code:

```
using Data;
using MyProject_API.Models.ViewModels;
using System.Linq;
using Utilities.Web.Authentication;

namespace MyProject_API.Services.EmailTemplates
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the <see cref="EmailTemplatesSearch" />
    /// </summary>
    public class EmailTemplatesSearch
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EmailTemplatesSearch"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataContext">The dataContext<see cref="DataContext"/></param>
        /// <param name="user">The user<see cref="MyProjectIdentity"/></param>
        public EmailTemplatesSearch(DataContext dataContext, MyProjectIdentity user)
        {
            _db = dataContext;
            _user = user;
        }
```

I've cleaned the code with help of `CodeFormatter` and get the following code:

```
namespace MyProject_API.Services.EmailTemplates
{
    using MyProject_API.Models.ViewModels;
    using System.Linq;
    using Utilities.Web.Authentication;

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the <see cref="EmailTemplatesSearch" />
    /// </summary>
    public class EmailTemplatesSearch
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EmailTemplatesSearch"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataContext">The dataContext<see cref="DataContext"/></param>
        /// <param name="user">The user<see cref="MyProjectIdentity"/></param>
        public EmailTemplatesSearch(DataContext dataContext, MyProjectIdentity user)
        {
            _db = dataContext;
            _user = user;
        }
```

As you can see, `CodeFormatter` looses `using Data;`. I've tried to add `using Data;` to the list of usings, but the code can't be compiled, `DataContext` which is in `Data` namespace can't be found. I fixed the problem moving `using Data;` outside from namespace, but it looks like a crutch. `DataContext` is defined like a

```
namespace Data
{
    public class DataContext
```

[image]

- Why `CodeFormatter` looses `using Data;`?
- Why `using Data;` doesn't work inside the namespace?

I've searched for similar questions:
[LINQ to SQL Designer Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292535/linq-to-sql-designer-bug) , [Should 'using' directives be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-directives-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace) , etc., but i still don't understand how to solve my issues

Comment: Do you have a conflicting namespace that includes `Data` in your solution/project/assembly?

Comment: The output of the code formatter is wrong.  Using statements should always be before a namespace.

Comment: What error do you see? Is it just DataContext does not exist in the current context? To me this feels like a conflict inside yout namespace. If you can see if there other data classes or similar?

Comment: @JazzmanJim `"Using statements should always be before a namespace"` -- will definitely need a source for that statement...

Comment: @maccettura well it is the better practice -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-directives-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace : but i do not like exclusive comments either.

Comment: Sometimes a version mismatch can cause this type of errors. If you have a project running .NET 4.5 and link to a project running 4.7 then the Code-Formatter/INtellisense will not notice and saying it's OK, but the real compiler complains - or vice versa. The same may appear on mismatching Build Configs like Any-CPU/x86. They can be linked but sometimes behave like invisible. Just something to check for compatibility.

Comment: @maccettura  You are right! Thank you!

I relied on  tools like R# and Code Formatter, and i get into this pitfall.

Codeformatter - didn't resolve namespaces correctly and removed correct using.
R# - when i tried to fix 'Can't resolve symbol DataContext' with help of R#, R# didn't find appropriate namespace.

When second time i was searching the conflicting namespace, according to your suggestion i used just simple search and found it.

Thank you all guys!