# .NET namespaces and using statements

Tags: .net, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should Usings be inside or outside the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

What is the difference between

```
namespace x
{
  using y;
}
```

and

```
using y;
namespace x
{
}
```

?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first one has y in scope for just the namespace x, the second has y in scope for the whole file, so potentialy other namespaces. If you keep to one namespace per file (I'd guess that was the convention) then there's *usually* no real difference [but see Marc's comment about clashes if different types have the same name in different namespaces]. If you use StyleCop it will want you to keep the usings inside the namespace.

Comment: Actually, I seem to recall that there *can* be a difference... *if* there are conflicting types etc at different levels.

Comment: And as another (more practical) difference... one of them can crash the LINQ-to-SQL code generator, and one doesn't ;-p

Answer (score 7):

Putting the `using` statement inside the `namespace` block scopes it to that block.  This affects a number of things.

1. As [@Steve Haigh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795098/net-namespaces-and-using-statements/795100#795100) mentioned, the `using` statement is only valid within the block, so if there were other `namespace` blocks, they wouldn't be affected.
2. The namespace specified by the `using` can be shortened based on the outer `namespace` block.  So `using x.y;` outside of the namespace can just be expressed as `using y;` inside of the `namespace x` block.
3. Putting the `using` inside of the namespace causes the compiler to guarantee that the specified namespace isn't overwritten.  For example:

   ```
       using Guid = System.Guid;
       namespace Sample
       {
           public class Guid {}
           public class Program
           {
               public static void Main()
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(new Guid());
               }
           }
       }
   ```

   The above code will compile, but it is unclear which `Guid` is being instantiated.  If the `using` statement is inside of the `namespace` block, however, a compiler error is thrown.

See [the related StyleCop documentation](http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/stylecop/sa1200.htm) for a more complete discussion.

Comment: +1. Interesting edge case there.