# Does it matter whether using statements are above or below the namespace declaration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, using

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should Usings be inside or outside the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

I've noticed that sometimes lately when I've used Visual Studio's "Resolve" feature to add using statements to a class or unit, it's been adding them *below* the namespace declaration. Although it doesn't seem to make any difference, it looks "weird" to me, so I copy and paste them up above "where they belong." Should I leave them be, or does it not matter which side of the namespace they lie?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795098/net-namespaces-and-using-statements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994380/net-namespace-what-is-exact-difference-in-writing-using-directives-before-o All answer this question.

Comment: And to be clear: `using`s can't be placed below a namesppace, only inside one.