# Stop Visual Studio from putting using directives outside namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, stylecop

Is there a setting in Visual Studio (or ReSharper) that allows you to specify what namespaces should be default and which scope they are put in?

The default for an MVC project for example is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Namespace
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

but ReSharper and StyleCop complain:

> All using directives must be placed inside of the namespace. [StyleCop Rule: SA1200]
> Using directive is not required by the code and can be safely removed

Is there a way to make the default simply:

```
namespace Namespace
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can edit the class template; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks. Voted to close this as a dupe :)

Comment: @dav_i: The answer may be a duplicate - but I'm guessing you didn't know that templates existed? So it may be worth keeping the question based on that fact.

Comment: Agreed. And thanks for your answer! Closing it as a dupe still keeps the question alive so people can still go `Google>This Q>That Q`.

Comment: I was interested to go and read about the StyleCop rule, as I'm used to seeing using directives outside of namespaces (Newtonsoft.Json, NodaTime, Jon Skeet's MiscUtil), and I found these questions which may interest other readers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/125319/397817 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1071797/397817

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally I don't believe there's any harm in including `using` statementents at the top of your class. I actually find it easier to include them there, so it's up to you whether you want to respect that rule.

If you do however, all of the file templates are available and can be edited. See the answer [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface) to detail where they live on each Visual Studio version.

Once you're there you can change the layout, so for example a basic class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

You could change this to the following or similar:

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
    $endif$using System.Text;
    $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
    $endif$

    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

There may be quite a few files to change though!

Comment: _Generally I don't believe there's any harm in including using statements at the top of your class_ - Compiler will search for directives starting from namespace internals and if not found will continue looking for directives outside of namespace. So - if you put directives outside of namespace and I will create class with same name inside namespace - then "my" class will be used. Putting directives inside namespace is very small effort for adding more safety in your code

Comment: In addition to Fabio's remark, the scope is just different so placing a using directive in-or outside a namespace is difference and can lead to problems.

Answer (score 26):

You can set this in Re-sharper.

Re-sharper > Options > C# > Namespace Imports > Add using directive to the deepest scope.

---

**Update**: As of VS2015 and Resharper10, this has moved. It is now under:

Code Editing > C# > Code Style > Reference qualification > Add 'using' directive to deepest scope

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This setting seems to only work when _adding_ namespaces. Not creating new files.

Comment: You can use the templates as suggested above, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface

Comment: Reset that flag works for ReSharper8.2 and VS2013. Way around.

Comment: In VS2015 and Resharper10 this section is empty and there is nowhere to configure this.

Comment: @Neutrino I can't seem to find this any more. Have you come across anything about this in August? Resharper no longer does the prompting for moving usings inside the namespace and therefore doesn't have the alt+enter combo to do so either.

Comment: It's now under Code Editing > C# > Code Style > Reference qualification > Add 'using' directive to deepest scope.

Comment: Moved again in resharper: It's now under Code Editing > C# > Syntax Style > Add 'using' directive to deepest scope.

Comment: Downvoted: non-free solution.

Answer (score 20):

There is an easier way to do it nowadays without modifying templates and without ReSharper. Ever since Visual Studio 2019 update 16.1
was released you can setup the usings inside the namespace by following these steps:

1. Open **Visual Studio**
2. In the toolbar, go to **Tools**
3. Within the Tools menu, open **Options**
4. In the options list, select the **Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General**
5. Scroll down near the bottom, find the **'using' preferences** section and set the ***Preferred 'using' directive placement*** to ***Inside namespace***

[image]

Comment: Appreciate it for suggesting a setting in Visual Studio and not in ReSharper

Comment: Also: `csharp_using_directive_placement = inside_namespace:suggestion` for your `.editorconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a Visual Studio extension for VS 2015 and 2017 that fixes `using` declarations after the fact. It also has some configuration options for grouping particular declarations (like `System.*`)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=everfor88.UsingDirectiveFormatter

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using .editorConfig you can add the following.

```
# 'using' directive preferences
csharp_using_directive_placement =inside_namespace:warning
```

Answer (score 1):

In ReSharper 2020, it's under Code Editing > C# > Syntax Style > Add 'using' directive to deepest scope.