# SA1200 vs. IDE0065

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

When using StyleCop, it recommends me to move my using statements inside the scope of my namespace (SA1200). However, if I follow that rule (which I've never heard of before), I get warning IDE0065, which suggests me to not put using statements into the namespace. So which of them is right and which of them is wrong? Or at least preferrable?

Comment: None is correct/both are correct. It's a matter of preference. You need to align your VS settings with your StyleCop settings.

Comment: Check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629264/stop-visual-studio-from-putting-using-directives-outside-namespace) to see how you can tweak either StyleCop or VS