# When creating a C# template in Visual Studio, my using directives are being moved out of the namespace, causing issues with my header

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629264/stop-visual-studio-from-putting-using-directives-outside-namespace), and applied the following formatting (changes where needed) to all files (Class\Class.cs, CodeFile\CodeFile.cs, Interface\Interface.cs, WebClass\CLass.cs):

```cs
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
    $endif$using System.Text;
    $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
    $endif$
    
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

My template files themselves look like so:

```cs
//

// Header

//
namespace $safeprojectname$
{
    using x;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But once I create a new file with the template, my file ends up looking like so:

```cs
// 

// Header

using x;
using y;

//
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

It's not difficult to fix by hand, but I wish it could be done automatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772071/17034

Comment: It seems that this answers your question: [Stop Visual Studio from putting using directives outside namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629264/stop-visual-studio-from-putting-using-directives-outside-namespace)

Comment: @showdev, I cited that as one of the things I tried, but thanks for the effort

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, that fixed it. Quick question though, why not post that as an answer?

Comment: You already posted the solution in your question, I just linked back to it.

Comment: @PavelSushko You said that post answered your question. Is that not the case? It's the post that includes the answer linked by Hans.

Comment: @showdev, yeah it's correct, I didn't check 3 answers down, that's my fault. Thank you