# When do we need to put using directives inside a namespace scope?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, code-organization, using-directives

I don't know why Asp.net MVC developers put the `using` directives inside `System.Web.Mvc` namespace as follows.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    [Serializable]
    public class ModelErrorCollection : Collection<ModelError>
    {

        public void Add(Exception exception)
        {
            Add(new ModelError(exception));
        }

        public void Add(string errorMessage)
        {
            Add(new ModelError(errorMessage));
        }
    }
}
```

When do we need to put  `using` directives inside a `namespace` scope?

Comment: I don't know if it's even necessary.  The only reason I could think of that might require that is if you have a source file that has multiple namespaces within it.  But how often to people _really_ do that?  Not a lot I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Should 'using' statements be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

Answer (score 2):

It's your choice. StyleCop tool warns of it as a best practice, however Visual Studio generated files always have usings outside namespace.

[Should all the using directives for namespaces be inside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955024/should-all-the-using-directives-for-namespaces-be-inside-the-namespace)