# Performance between importing entire namespace versus using alias in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, namespaces, alias, using

Is there a performance difference at all between importing an entire namespace versus using aliasing to import only one class? If so, how much of a difference is it?

Examples:

Importing an entire namespace:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Aliasing to import only one class:

```
using BindingFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [does 'using' provide any advantages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911141/does-using-provide-any-advantages)

Comment: An alias should cause less clutter being offered by ImpediDense, er, IntelliSense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Zero. Namespace imports are a compile-time feature and the generated IL will be exactly the same either way.

Comment: What about at runtime when the assemblies are to be loaded? Wouldn't only the classes specified be loaded and not all classes in an entire namespace?

Comment: @Brandon The performance implications are in adding the .dll as a reference to the project.  Adding a `using` statement has no effect on what is or is not loaded from those dlls.

Comment: @Brandon: This is a different aspect altogether. Namespace imports are simply time savers / readability enhancements for the source code, the resulting code is exactly the same as if you had typed out things like System.Collections.Generic.List<string> (for example). Assembly loading and type resolution aren't directly related to namespace imports.

Comment: @Alan I just want to clarify that I understand you correctly: You're saying that when compiled, the exact same code is generated...regardless of how I've imported my namespace? I.E. where I see `Exception e` in my source code, I would actual see `System.Exception e` (or some reference to that effect) regardless of aliasing or entire namespace imports in the compiled code?

Comment: @Brandon: Exactly, yes. (Also, you can use Reflector or any other IL disassembler to verify.)

Answer (score 5):

No it is just an help for the programmer, the CIL generated by the compiler is exactly the same.

Comment: No CIL is generated for either, is it?  What would it contain?  It's a compile-time directive

Comment: @KierenJohnstone: Of course, I meant to say that the CIL generated for the whole program is the same.

Answer (score 3):

There's no performance difference.  One says 'look here when I specify a class name, it might be in here'.  The other says 'when I say this class or namespace, I mean use this one'.

Answer (score -1):

No but even more broad.  You load the dll that contains the .net core and it'll have dozens of namespaces in it.  You really don't take a hit for importing namespaces till you walk outside of the already loaded dll.