# the right place to put the references to the libraries in C#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should Usings be inside or outside the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

Hi,

Actually we have two conventions, like 
1.

```
namespace FullFeaturedApp
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using User;

    public class UserManager : Controller{....}
}
```

2.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using User;
namespace FullFeaturedApp
{
    public class UserManager : Controller
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

What is the difference between these two systems.

Comment: Can't find the duplicate question...

Comment: Also see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/25/inside-or-outside.aspx