# What's the difference of different location of "using statement"?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should Usings be inside or outside the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

Hi, friends,

What's the difference between the following 2 code snippets? The using statement is located differently.

```
namespace CodedUITest
{
    using System;
}
```

and

```
using System;
namespace CodedUITest
{

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: For those with the same question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace