# namespace not found!

Tags: c#, .net, reference, using

I created a solution called `Foo`.
Added a class library called `Foo.Common`
Added a console app to call the library code from called `ConsoleApp`.

**I referenced the `Foo.Common` from `ConsoleApp`** and typed :

```
using Foo.Common;
public class Program
{
    CommonClass c = new CommonClass();            

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

and get this back :

`Error  1   The type or namespace name '**Foo**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Z:\Foo\Solution1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 3   11  ConsoleApplication1`

Why am i getting this?

what s going on?

Comment: Is CommonClass declared as `public`? If not, you cannot use it outside the Foo.Common class library.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?  If so, the Object Browser (View menu) will show you the loaded namespaces.

Comment: It s showing Foo.Common. But the compiler is looking for Foo namespace. WTF?

Comment: Move the using statement out of the namespace declaration?

Comment: If you have a `using Foo.Bar.Baz;` directive and the compiler cannot find `Foo.Bar.Baz`, it looks for `Foo.Bar`. And if it cannot find that, it looks for `Foo`. If it cannot find that as well, it says that `Foo` could not be found, even though it was originally looking for `Foo.Bar.Baz`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that

- The *ConsoleApp* project has a reference to the *Foo.Common* **project** (do *not* browse for Foo.Common.dll),

  [image: Screenshot]
- the file contains a `using` directive for the namespace in which `CommonClass` is declared, and
- `CommonClass` is declared as `public`.

So your files should look like this:

---

*CommonClass.cs* in *Foo.Common* project:

```
namespace Foo.Common
{
    public class CommonClass
    {
        public CommonClass()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Program.cs* in *ConsoleApp* project:

```
using Foo.Common;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            CommonClass x = new CommonClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it s exactly like this. but when i compiled, i m getting compilation error as above.

Comment: That s exactly how I added the reference via Projects tab.

Comment: Ok the errro was due to Project was in .net 4 client profile in the settings.

Comment: @Foo Bar you last comment must be answer :)))

Comment: @FooBar please make your comment the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that under your project settings, the target framework is set as .NET Framework 4 and not .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.  I got this same behavior when it was set to Client Profile and it was fixes as soon as I set it to just the regular .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the new console app solution/project and Add Reference and add the project that contains the Foo namespace

Comment: I dont have a Foo namespace. I have Foo.Common

Comment: and i added Foo.Common library as a reference.

Comment: so it looks like namspace Foo.Common { public class CommonClass ... } in the other solution?

Comment: When you type does the autocomplete show Foo.Common? If anything try Foo.Common.CommonClass = new Foo.Common.CommonClass()

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a reference to the library?  Look under "References" in the console project.  If its not there, you need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this as a comment, but I want to expand on it here.  What's probably happening is it's seeing using as a statement and not a keyword.  It appears you have something like the following:

```
using System;
namespace TestNamespace
{
  using Foo.Common;
  public Class { }
}
```

Try

```
using System;
using Foo.Common;
namespace TestNamespace
{
  public Class { } 
}
```

Instead.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to have a `using` directive inside a namespace declaration. There is no ambiguity with a `using` statement.

Comment: Indeed, not only is it valid, but some people strongly recommend it, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/125319/180803) has some good information. Although, having one `using` inside the namespace and one outside is surely not good style!

Comment: Yeah, I realized that shortly after I posted, it's really useful for doing namespace aliasing.  Still, I thought it might be related, guess it was the .net 4 client profile thing though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Foo Bar got this error because his project's target framework was set to the client profile.

Just thought I'd add one more 'solution' -- I created a library that targeted the 4.5 framework.  My older project was tarting the 4 framework.  I got this error.

Changing the older project to 4.5 made it work.