# Using - inside namespace or outside namespace

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should Usings be inside or outside the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

We all, I think, write usings and then namespace at the beggining of a class. I just saw a code that the namespace comes first. What's the difference?

Comment: not getting you at all can you share some code here

Comment: If you using the full set of StyleCop settings, they recommend `using`s inside the `namespace`, don't know why though.