# How to diagnose an issue with csproj references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I have an issue with a class being used in another project.

Visual studio is able to add a `using` statement using `Resolve` (`Ctrl+.`), but:

> The type or namespace name 'SomeClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Resolving this again fully qualifies the type but the namespace in the type path is highlighted as not being found.

The namespace appears also in intellisense and the target class is visible in the Object Browser.

Removing unused namespaces removes the added `using` statement.

I've tried:

1. Rebuild.
2. Confirm project dependency in solution options.
3. Delete reference and re-add.
4. Confirm class accessibility (despite namespace not being found).
5. Checked build mode (Debug/Release).
6. Restart Visual Studio.
7. Cleared `bin` folders in both projects.
8. Restart machine.

What is the next step to diagnosing this baffling issue?

Comment: If you are targeting .NET 4 then try to change to the full version, not the Client profile.

Comment: Can you see the type in the Object Browser? Maybe you are not loading the assembly you think you are loading.

Comment: @Philipp, that was one of the things I tried, to make sure, will update question.

Comment: Use a decompiler to check the class actually exists in the bin dll you are referencing.

Comment: @TheCodeKing They're in there. They're so in there. I can't believe how in there they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by similar namespaces e.g. `Company.Product.Project` and `Product.Project` with:

```
namespace Company.Product.Project
{
        using Product.Project;
```

The class was in `Product.Project`, but the compiler was searching for `Company.Product.Project`.

See: [Should 'using' statements be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace/151560#151560) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be a .Net framework versioning issue. The class being referenced was probably built using a higher version of the framework.

Try checking your framework versions all align in properties, build settings. A project cannot reference an assembly of a higher framework version.

Comment: Nope, they are both the same version. Is there more granularity other than that Target Framework dropdown containing {2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0}?

Comment: There's whether it's client profile or not, other than that no. What you are experiencing is usually this issue. Is the dll copied to the bin?

Comment: It's not, and I've gone through: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668079.aspx with no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had this problem my class was not marked public.  Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks Decker, the namespace is what's not found and I don't think you can modify the accessibility of a namespace. Checking the class(es)  was number 4 on my list.

Comment: What happens if you put in the namespace.class.function directly? sometimes it will give rollover help for why it's not found.

Comment: Resolving this again fully qualifies the type but the namespace in the type path is highlighted as not being found.