# Code Cleanup make visual studio put usings inside namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am adding stylecop to one of our projects and one of its recommendations is to nest usings inside the namespace. I wondered if there was a way to make Visual Studio do this by default?

I know with resharper that I can be  [done 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160820/code-cleanup-tool-to-move-all-using-statements-inside-namespace-in-all-cs-file) however I don't have re-sharper for this project, I wondered if it was possible to make VisualStudio do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the "New Class" template using the instructions suggested here:

[How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface).