# including using in namespace

Tags: c#

I have been wondering what is better way of using code.
Is there any difference between writing using inside of namespace:

ouside of namespace

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Myproject.DataLayer;


namespace Myproject
{
  public class MyProjectClass{
  // etc
  }
}
```

Inside of namespace
 the only reason i can thing of : shorter names, and the complier does not need to go to global location to find the implementation... but not sure about the rest

```
namespace Myproject
{
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using DataLayer;

  public class MyProjectClass{
  // etc
  }
}
```

Comment: It might help [Should using be inside or outside][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott have already answered the question at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDoNamespaceUsingDirectivesAffectAssemblyLoading.aspx

Value of keeping the using code & Alias names inside namespace incase if you decide to have multiple namespaces in one file.

But the question to ask yourself is why do I want to have multiple namespace's in the same file