# The type 'X' does not exist in the type 'Y.Z'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, compiler-errors

Our team has recently migrated from Visual Studio 2008/.NET3.5 to Visual Studio 2010/.NET4.0. Now, VS2010 gives me a strange error message. It's reproducible with the following program:

```
using System;

namespace Some.Main
{
}

namespace SomeLib
{
    interface Some
    {
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using Some.Main;
    using SomeLib;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Press enter to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This worked just fine in VS2008, but in VS2010 I get the following error message:

> The type name 'Main' does not exist in the type 'SomeLib.Some'

Interestingly, if I hit 'Build Solution', the program builds just fine, and I can even execute it without any problems. It's just Visual Studio that seems to have a problem with this code.

Unfortunately, I'm working on a large-ish legacy application and I cannot (easily) change the names of these namespaces.

I'd like to know how I can fix this error, and I'm also curious what causes it.

Comment: try `using global::Some.Main;`

Comment: It's funny. That exact code, compiles on Mono (latest). But on Visual Studio 2010, it doesn't

Comment: @MichaelBuen It's even worse, because on Visual Studio 2008, it also compiles.

Comment: ideone uses Mono for its C#. See your code here, compiles fine http://ideone.com/zmLCO

Comment: perhaps asking Eric Lippert is a good idea. He could explain the discrepancy

Comment: @jqno I think you've found a bug on Visual Studio 2010 ツ Language-wise, your code is perfectly valid, it even builds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply make the editor *confused*. `Some` is both a namespace and an interface name, evidently it doesn't check/parse `using`s in the order they're declared.

If you want to make clear you're referring to the namespace and not the type name simply add `global::` to the `using` declaration (to start from the *root* namespace), like this:

```
using global::Some.Main;
```

**UPDATE**
Very good post here on SO linked by @alex in a comment: [Should 'using' statements be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

Answer (score 4):

I think IntelliSense is confused by the naming and doesn't "understand" who's who.

Attached screenshot demonstrates what's going on: IntelliSense "thinks" `Some.Main` refers to the interface named `Some`, probably because there isn't a namespace called `Some` anywhere.

Luckily, the compiler isn't fooled like that and the code seems to work just fine, like you said.

[image: IntelliSense being fooled]

Comment: And after you do a build, IntelliSense stops complaining too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Until you make a change; then it comes back :).

Comment: @HenkHolterman And that's more funny, I tried building it, it compiles. Yet it has error when you make changes to code. Are the Visual Studio IDE team and C# compiler team a separate team?

Comment: @MichaelBuen I guess they're but more than that they use pretty different techniques to parse code. For Intellisense they key point is speed and error-tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using Some.Main;
using SomeLib;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    // instead of placing usings here.
}
```

Comment: Beware, moving `using`s around might lead to code breaking and should *not* be done blindly! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace

Comment: @alex: however I always place using out of namespace and never hear any problems.