# Can "using <namespace>;" directives be made more efficient in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, using, stylecop

When I create a new class file in C#, the usual structure is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace UnitTest
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

StyleCop doesn't like having using directives outside of the namespace, so ideally, I would refactor my code as such:

```
namespace UnitTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

From my days as a Java programmer, I was taught that it was better to import only the references that were necessary, rather than the entire package like so:

```
import foo.bar.MyObject;
```

instead of

```
import foo.bar.*;
```

I know that this can also be done in C#, with the added feature that you can use aliases for types (sometimes useful when working though native code):

```
using StringBuilder = System.Text.StringBuilder;
```

or when using aliases:

```
using HANDLE = System.IntPtr;
using HDC = System.IntPtr;
```

So my questions, regarding best practice and efficiency of using directives:

1. Is is more efficient to keep using statements inside a namespace, or is this purely a stylistic preference?
2. If is more efficient to only include the necessary items, as opposed to the entire namespace?

Comment: edited: those are using *directives*, not using *statements* - big difference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks! Sorry that could have been a little confusing

Comment: Use only what you need makes sense to prevent naming conflicts which are rare. For me the using part is just noise so i try to reduce it as much a possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There are [some fringe cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace) where it makes a difference but for the majority of cases it is just a stylistic preference.
2. The using statements just tell the compiler where it can locate the types. It has no influence on the runtime.

Answer (score 3):

1. nope; stylistic preference, as long as it doesn't introduce any semantic changes; the cases where it changes the meaning are very rare (although there used to be a bug with the LINQ-to-SQL code generator that *did* care about where you put them - this is now fixed)
2. nope; unused directives are not used, and they don't massively impact the compiler

Note that having too many directives can cause ambiguities; for example there are a myriad of classes called `Timer`. For that reason it is worth keeping things tidy.

Comment: Does .NET's mechanism differ from Java? I ask because as stated, I was taught that in Java, you should only import specific objects, not the enter package, as this may impact performance when loading the package. Either I was taught incorrectly, or .NET is just different?

Comment: @series0ne I don't know how java handles that - so I can't say whether it is *different*; but that is not a concern in .NET