# C# source file amalgamation

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, thrift

I use a tool that generates c# source code (thrift), one file per type.  I would like to amalgamate all of the types to a single compilable source file.  I say compilable because simply concatenating the text from each file will produce a single file that does not compile do to the layout, e.g. multiple using blocks.

Is there a command line tool that will do this, or do I need to create one and if so what libs should I be looking at to do so.

=======  EDIT  ======

Didn't find anything and wimped out of contributing to thrift compiler source, so I knocked this up which does the trick: https://github.com/myles-mcdonnell/SourceMeld

Now I can add two pre-build steps in VS, one to exe thrift to generate source files, two to amalgamate to one file (the file that is include in project) and I have a seamless build process at dev time.

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate the source files if you write them in smart way.

See, this doesn't work:

```
using External.Name.Space;
namespace My.Name.Space
{
    ...
}

using External.Name.Space;
namespace My.Name.Space
{
    ...
}
```

But this does:

```
namespace My.Name.Space
{
    using External.Name.Space;

    ...
}

namespace My.Name.Space
{
    using External.Name.Space;

    ...
}
```

These two notations are mostly functionally equivalent (for details, see "[Should Usings be inside or outside the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)").

Tools like ReSharper can transform all your source files from the first notation to the second in several clicks (even the free trial version can do that).

EDIT:

I forgot you are using a code generator. Then you have these options:

1. Change Thrift's templates (I'm not familiar with the tool, but I would expect it has templates of some sort).
2. Write a tool which moves the usings from outside of a namespace within. This should be a single Regex.Replace call.
3. Write a tool which reads the concatenated file and moves all the usings to the top. Again, this should be extremely simple.

Comment: "Smart way" is a poor choice of words, but the idea will work.

Comment: That is an option, but it would require me to extend/change the thrift compiler.  I'm hoping to find a post generation solution.

Comment: @MatějZábský: There are no real templates. The generated code is assembled piece by piece during compiler run.