# Why do I need fully qualified name to access static property of a class that was included with "using"

Tags: c#, namespaces

If I have this class declaration

```
namespace DatabaseCache
{
    public class DatabaseCache 
    {
        public static bool somePublicFlag ;
    }
}
```

In another class I have this statement

```
using DatabaseCache;
```

Why do i need to write a statement like this in that class

```
DatabaseCache.DatabaseCache.somePublicFlag = true ;
```

instead of just

```
DatabaseCache.somePublicFlag = true ;
```

Comment: You need to resolve the collison between `DatabaseCache` as a namespace and as a class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need that if you don't have a `Namespace` and `Type` name collision. A well designed library will not have such collision, So design your library accordingly to avoid such collision.

```
namespace DatabaseCache
{
    //change the name of the class
    public class DifferentNameThanNamespace
    {
        public static bool somePublicFlag ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to test that, but I rather learn from the masters

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid ambiguities, it is not recommanded to declare a class with the same same as its namespace.

The **[Framework Design Guidelines say in section 3.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182257.aspx)** “do not use the same name for a namespace.

To learn about how to activate/disable this kind of warning see this [**link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264939%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to activate warnings for this kind of guidelines to be aplied in my code ?

Comment: Yes of course, it is in the Analysis menu of visual studio, you have to perform some configuration to see this warning : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907198.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler doesn't know if `DatabaseCache` is referring to the *namespace* or the *class*.  Even thought you're `using` the namespace it's still perfectly legal to preface types within that namespace by the namespace, so the call is ambiguous.

You *could* alias the type by using:

```
using DC = DatabaseCache.DatabaseCache;
```

and then just calling

```
DC.somePublicFlag
```

but that's just masking the problem - renaming the namespace is a better solution.

Comment: You: _Because the compiler doesn't know if `DatabaseCache` is referring to the namespace or the class._ Technically, the compiler knows very well what `DatabaseCache` refers to, because there are rules for which order to search for matches for the identifier `DatabaseCache`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

(Of course the advice is to not use the same name for two distinct things.)

Answer with an extension. Suppose you have one file with:

```
namespace DatabaseCache
{
  public class DatabaseCache  // same name as namespace :-(
  {
    public static bool somePublicFlag;
  }

  public class somePublicFlag  // evil other type
  {
  }
}
```

Then now it depends on where you put your `using` directives relative to your `namespace`. For example, in another file, this will be legal:

```
namespace Other
{
  using DatabaseCache;

  class DbcTestClass1
  {
    void M()
    {
      DatabaseCache.somePublicFlag = true;  // legal!
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, `somePublicFlag` refers to the field of the class!

However, this is legal as well:

```
using DatabaseCache;

namespace Other
{
  class DbcTestClass2
  {
    void M()
    {
      var instance = new DatabaseCache.somePublicFlag();  // legal!
    }
  }
}
```

With that placing of the `using` directive, the `somePublicFlag` refers to the "evil" class of that name. The qualifier `DatabaseCache.` in this case is redundant, but it is still seen as a reference to the namespace `global::DatabaseCache` because the global namespace (`null` namespace) is searched first in this case.

To learn more, see [my answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16092975/1336654). It all depends on the order in which the different namespaces (including the global namespace) are searched for a matching name.