# Using and namespace

Tags: c#

Where to place using System or other namespaces?
Which is the correct or the better way to write code and why?
According to my c# trainer it is the second, but everywhere I see the first one.

```
using System;
namespace Program
{
    class SomeClass
    {
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace Program
{
using System;

    class SomeClass
    {
    }
}
```

According to my c# trainer it is the second, but everywhere I see the first one.

Comment: Your C# trainer probably has a Java background and doesn't know better...

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812088/differences-between-using-import-inside-or-outside-of-namespace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of a using directive is limited to the file in which it appears.

Create a using alias to make it easier to qualify an identifier to a namespace or type. The right side of a using alias directive must always be a fully-qualified type regardless of the using directives that come before it.

Create a using directive to use the types in a namespace without having to specify the namespace. A using directive does not give you access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify.

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is your choice. The second can be handy if you have a code file with multiple namespaces, but only want to use a namespace import within one of these namespaces. However, most coding guidelines that I have seen so far specify that a file may only contain one namespace at most and the usings at the top of the file, in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 1):

Stylecop by default requires you to put usings inside namespaces - see [here](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1200.html); for the following reason: (from linked page):

There are subtle differences between placing using directives within a namespace element, rather than outside of the namespace, including:

1. Placing using-alias directives within the namespace eliminates compiler confusion between conflicting types.
2. When multiple namespaces are defined within a single file, placing using directives within the namespace elements scopes references and aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Using is always on the top of the document.

Comment: Why's that? The other way it compiles, too?

Comment: @Devcon this is not a requirement.