# Why isn't this class reference ambiguous?

Tags: c#, ambiguous

I am wondering why this situation is not resulting in an ambiguous reference between types, one a class within our library and one an external struct. Consider the following-

External struct-

```cs
namespace External.Models
{
    public struct ProxyUser
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Our class-

```cs
namespace MyApp.Configuration
{
    public class ProxyUser
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then the calling code approximates-

```cs
using External.Models;

namespace MyApp.Configuration.Factories
{
    sealed class Factory
    {
        public async Task<T> BuildConfiguration<T>()
        {
            var proxy = new ProxyUser { Username = username, Password = password }; // I would expect this to be ambiguous, but it references out class
        }
    }
}
```

This is a NetStandard 2.0 library if that makes a difference. Behavior is the same if I make our class a struct. Why isn't this ambiguous?

**EDIT** - Class is sealed, again if that makes a difference...

**ANSWER**

As @Sinatr mentioned, it appears to be related to this question- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25437586/14872099

This is a demonstration of the different behaviors I observed.

This resolves to our `MyApp.Configuration.ProxyUser`-

```cs
using External.Models;

namespace MyApp.Configuration.Factories
{
    sealed class Factory
    {
        public async Task<T> BuildConfiguration<T>()
        {
            var proxy = new ProxyUser { Username = username, Password = password }; // resolves to our class
        }
    }
}
```

This resolves to the external struct-

```cs
namespace MyApp.Configuration.Factories
{
    using External.Models;

    sealed class Factory
    {
        public async Task<T> BuildConfiguration<T>()
        {
            var proxy = new ProxyUser { Username = username, Password = password }; // resolves to external struct
        }
    }
}
```

Moving our class to another namespace creates ambiguity-

```cs
using External.Models;
using MyApp.Configuration.Models; // moved our class to this namespace

namespace MyApp.Configuration.Factories
{
    sealed class Factory
    {
        public async Task<T> BuildConfiguration<T>()
        {
            var proxy = new ProxyUser { Username = username, Password = password }; // this is ambiguous
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are inside the same namespace group. Both classes are inside the `MyApp.Configuration` namespace.

Comment: It makes sense why it is aware of our `ProxyUser` class, but not why this isn't ambiguous. Are you aware of anything documenting how ambiguity is determined?

Comment: Do you get warnings? I am unable to find a topic regarding how compiler resolve best type to match. AFAIR local assembly types have precedence, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25437199/1997232).

Comment: Most probably that is due to `using`s, you import only one namespace, so you don't get the errors.

Comment: This answer seems to be it. Since the `using` statement is outside our namespace, it is in the global namespace and takes a backseat to our namespace. Moving the using statement inside our namespace causes it to reference the external struct.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25437586/14872099

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same fully qualified classname in multiple assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437199/same-fully-qualified-classname-in-multiple-assemblies)

Answer (score 2):

Internal namespaces (i.e. inside the `namespace` brackets) get priority over external namespaces (i.e. `using` statements before the `namespace` block).

*Note: "internal" and "external" aren't official definitions here, I just use these to easily distinguish between them.*

Due to nesting, your `namespace MyApp.Configuration.Factories` block inherently also looks at any direct ancestors (`MyApp.Configuration` and `MyApp`), but not sibling namespaces (e.g. `MyApp.Configuration.Services`).

When a non-ambiguous reference is found in the internal namespaces, the system never bothers to check the external namespaces, and thus does not find a conflict. You'd only encounter a conflict if:

- There are two valid options in the internal namespace, e.g. `MyApp.Configuration.ProxyUser` and `MyApp.Configuration.Factories.ProxyUser`
- There are two valid options in the referenced external namespaces, e.g. `External.Models.ProxyUser` and `Another.Namespace.ProxyUser` (assuming both are referenced with `using` statements in this file)