# What is correct method to declare using statements (inside namespace or outside namespace)

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am running StyleCop over my C# code and it keeps reporting that my using statements should be inside the namespace.

Is this correct? Where i should keep this?

Both code is working fine, but i want to know what is correct way?

Comment: Duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-statements-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace

Comment: Here after please do search in Google. You will save much time to yourself. Cheers