# How does C# pick when two class names collide

Tags: c#

I have the following two files:

**IGlobalApiProvider.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Vert.Slack;

namespace Vert.Interfaces
{
    public interface IGlobalApiProvider
    {
        List<Im> ImList();
    }
}
```

And the corresponding implementation: **SlackApi.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Vert.Interfaces;

namespace Vert.Slack
{
    public class SlackApi : IGlobalApiProvider
    {
        public List<Im> ImList()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now, Intellisense is telling me that when I use `IM` in `IGlobalApiProvider` it's resolving to `Im`, which is defined in a file named **RtmStart.cs** which has *no namespace declaration*. When I use `IM` in **SlackApi.cs**, it's resolving to `Vert.Slack.Im` which is defined in the Vert.Slack namespace in a file named **Im.cs**. The weird behavior alerted me to the redundant definition, so I removed it and things are working fine.

However, I'm confused about why Visual Studio behaved differently in these two ways. I can tell something was scanning for the class names in a different pattern in the two situations. I can also tell that being used in the same namespace vs being used in a class that *uses* the namespace seems to be the trigger. What I don't know is what mechanism controls the logic behind this behavior.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Everything you see is contained in **Vert.dll**, which consists of one project, **Vert.csproj**

[Link to the four files mentioned in this post as they existed at the time of writing](http://1drv.ms/1Nmqe8n).

Comment: Need more information: Are they in the same project or not?

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of both classes? Seems like it should give you an ambiguity error, as you have `Vert.Slack.Im` defined in two places. It's not a partial class, is it? Are they both `public`?

Comment: Are you sure you have written that correctly? Having two definitions for `Im`  in the namespace `Vert.Slack` would give a compilation error.

Comment: Full context linked in an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the difference between the `global` and `Vert.Slack` namespaces.

The *compiler* looks for the most explicit namespace with the proper class defined.

In this example, when the compiler looks for the definition of `Im` in **IGlobalInterfaceProvider.cs**, there is no namespace defined (or used) in this file that contains the class, but `Im` is also defined *in this file* - which is declared in the global namespace.

When the compiler looks for the definition of `Im` in **SlackApi.cs**, `Im` is found in the explicit `Vert.Slack` namespace, and utilizes that class.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-statements-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace) is a similar topic and may provide more insight.

Answer (score -1):

This may be related to the fact that your namespaces are in the wrong place ;-)

http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1200.html

This answer here gives a good explanation: [Should 'using' statements be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-statements-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question (I recently updated the namespaces of the two implementing classes), as I am only ever using `using` outside of a namespace (or without a namespace). I'm looking for an answer that outlines *how* C# looks for class names.

Comment: The accepted answer of the linked question *does* explain exactly how the compiler resolves name ambiguities. However, answers which are just a link are discouraged. If you're not going to take the time to explain what's in the link, then write a comment instead of an answer

Comment: I'd love to comment but I'm not allowed yet.  Just trying to help.

Comment: @Allan I know, me too! :) You might want to have a look at the links section of the [guide to writing a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) as well as [referencing others' work](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).