# Why C# doesn't throw error on ambiguous namespaces?

Tags: c#

Assume we have two projects with different namespaces.

```
using Models = SharedClasses;

namespace MainAspNetMvcApplication{
   private void Method1(){
     var c = new Models.Cat();
     //Error    CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Cat' does not exist in the namespace 'MainAspNetMvcApplication.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
   }
}

namespace MainAspNetMvcApplication.Models{
  //There is no class `Cat` in this namespace
  public class Dog {
    ...
  }
  ...

}
```

I have added reference to a `SharedClasses` which contains following code.

```
namespace SharedClasses{
  public class Cat{
    //The code for shared classe (Cat)
  }
}
```

This is more like to an ambiguous `Models` error. However C# assumes current project `Models` namespace and throws `CS0234` error.

Why by default c# assume current project `Models` namespace while I have mentioned to use `Models` for `SharedClasses` ?

For me, the highest priority should be considered for `using Models = SharedClasses;`

Shouldn't at least C# let me know I have two ambiguous `Models` instead of choosing one ?

Just curious why C# designed like this. While I'm looking for language designers to answer any other related answer is welcome.

Comment: Did you include your namespace or put an assembly reference somewhere? <doesn't appear clear to me>

Comment: @devRicher I have added the reference, and it's also included with `using Models = SharedClasses;`

Comment: What if you dont use Models = SharedClasses?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. You want specification reference (AFAIK, behavior, you see, conform specification)? Or you want to language designers to answer, why them design C# like this?

Comment: @mayu Nothing changes. The same error on the same line.

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure that the error message is the same. If you dont use the word Models why would the compiler complain about Cat not being in Models?

Comment: To be clear - I suggest removing the 'using' line and changing 'new Models.Cat' to 'new SharedClasses.Cat'.

Comment: Your `using` directive is _outside_ the `namespace` declaration. Therefore, when there is an ambiguity (`Models` can refer to several things), the type or namespace existing in an "inner" scope is preferred over the `using` directive which is in an "outside" scope. See [my answer elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16092975/1336654) for details. For that reason, no ambiguity compile-time error is issued in this case for `Models`; there are rules determining which type or namespace the compiler must pick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No alias is something different.

```
using Models = SharedClasses;
```

Now `Models` is an alias not a namespace, so it is not ambigious namespace there are multiple rules outlining behavior of aliases you can find them here:

[Using alias directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx)