# I want namespace position change when each new namespace added

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I want namespace position change when each new namespace added. but I dont know how to do it.

Normally namespaces list is over the namespace define row but I want automatic add namespace list under the namespace define row.

I'm always moved the namespace list under the namespace define row but boring this method.

How I automatic to do it?

[image]

Comment: Hmm..may I ask you why?

Comment: Because, I think my codes more organized, readable, accessible with this method.

Comment: Maybe that would be more readable to you, but probably it would drive crazy to anyone who have to look at your code :)

Comment: This is not just a 'cosmetic' decision, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-statements-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace

Comment: I don't see an option to change this in plain VS. There may be an option if you're using an extra tool like Resharper?

Comment: I'm using Resharper, unfortunalety doesn't have any option with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you what I have done.

Go to :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class
```

I am using VS2013, so I go to Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 folder.

The Class.cs file is the template for the new classes that get created. In this file move the namespace bit around and voila !!

This will do:

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
    $endif$using System.Text;
    $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
    $endif$

    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```