# 'Color' is an ambiguous reference between 'Xamarin.Forms.Color' and 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xna

I get an error message in this line:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
```

Error CS0104: 'Color' is an ambiguous reference between 'Xamarin.Forms.Color' and 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color'

I know that I could change it to:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.CornflowerBlue);
```

But it's annoying to write always "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.". Is it possible to avoid writing "Microsoft.Xna.Framework."? How can I shorten/simplify the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign an alias to your namespace:

```
using xna = Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
```

then you can write

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(xna.Color.CornflowerBlue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following with your using statements as the top of the class:

```
using Color = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color;
```

Then you can use as you were originally doing:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right you could write the namespace with the Color-Type you are most likely to use into your namespace and the other one above the namespace (as it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/125319/8004636))