# Why do I get an error when this type exists in two assemblies even though I qualified the type?

Tags: c#

Why do I get an error when this type exists in two assemblies even though I qualified the type?

```
loadingMachine = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<CustomMachine>(f);
```

> Error CS0433  The type 'Serializer' exists in both 'devDept.Geometry.v2020, Version=2020.1.146.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9440825e8b4733bc' and 'protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67'   EyeShot test    J:\Jobb\DotnetDev\EyeShot Test\EyeShot test\EyeShot test\Form1.cs   49  Active

Comment: What's the namespace of the `Serializer` class in the `devDept.Geometry.v2020` assembly? Is the namespace the same in both assemblies? Or does the full name of the class end with `ProtoBuf.Serializer`?

Comment: Show us more detail about what these types are

Comment: Error is quite straightforward... you have the same method defined in two different places. I would recommend making them internal or removing the one from current project and simply use the method from protobuf-net

Comment: They are in different namespaces. One is in devDept.Serialization and the other one in the Protobuf namespace. These are both in different third-party libraries so I can not change them. I don't understand why qualifying the type does not work.

Comment: public static class Serializer
    Member of ProtoBuf
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

public abstract class Serializer
    Member of devDept.Serialization

Comment: @Electron8 Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code of the `Form1.cs` file you have and mark the line with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiler error happens when there is 2 library **referenced** to the project, both having the same namespace/class name within, that you attempt to use.

If you cannot rename one, you need to set an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433) for one.

**Point of interest:**

I found a worth to read answer in a related topic: [using-directive solution (for inner classes) to prevent compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-directives-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace#151560).

Comment: Nope sorry. I don't have protobuf in the usings.

Comment: Well, maybe I got it wrong then. Try to put it to the using section with an alias. Also you can follow this article, if it help I will edit my answer to the new solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433

Comment: Solved! Thanks, I ended up solving it by changing the Aliases property for the assembly. Your link pointed me in the right direction.