# "using static" kills AsParallel

Tags: c#, plinq

In the following code, if you uncomment the "using static" line, the query will not run in parallel. Why?

(Visual Studio Community 2019, .Net Core 3.1 / .Net 4.8)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace UsingStatic_Mystery
{
    //using static Enumerable;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var w = new Stopwatch();
            iter:
            w.Start();
            var xx = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                .AsParallel()
                .OrderByDescending(x => {
                    Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(100));
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                    return x;
                }).ToArray();
            w.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (var x in xx) Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(w.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
            w.Reset();
            goto iter;
        }
    }
}
```

output, uncommented/commented:

[image: "using static" uncommented]
[image: "using static" commented]

Comment: The correct syntax is [`using static <fully-qualified-type-name>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static), so `using static System.Linq.Enumerable;`

Comment: @MikeTsayper Your conclusion is correct. The compiled code changes.

Comment: @AluanHaddad on my pc it runs for about 600 ms uncommented, 200 commented, output sequential/shuffled

Comment: @xanatos even with the fully qualified name, the problem persists

Comment: It appears that "ToArray" binds to different extension methods when commenting/uncommenting the using static. I'm made a simpler repro, and [reported](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50916) to Roslyn team for investigation (it's not necessarily a bug, I'm not sure).

Comment: @Youssef13 Good find. I would however expect that to be "working as designed".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found:

This is the [IL code generated](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) with the `using static` commented (so **no `using static`**):

```
IL_0038: call class [System.Linq.Parallel]System.Linq.OrderedParallelQuery`1<!!0> [System.Linq.Parallel]System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable::OrderByDescending<int32, int32>(class [System.Linq.Parallel]System.Linq.ParallelQuery`1<!!0>, class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>)
IL_003d: call !!0[] [System.Linq.Parallel]System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable::ToArray<int32>(class [System.Linq.Parallel]System.Linq.ParallelQuery`1<!!0>)
```

and this is the [IL code generated](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) with the `using static` uncommented (so **with `using static`**):

```
IL_0038: call class [System.Linq]System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Linq]System.Linq.Enumerable::OrderByDescending<int32, int32>(class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>)
IL_003d: call !!0[] [System.Linq]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToArray<int32>(class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
```

The "correct" side is using `Parallel.OrderBy`, the "wrong" side is using `Enumerable.OrderBy`. The result you see is quite clearly for this reason. And the reason for why one or the other `OrderBy` is selected is because with the `using static Enumerable` you declare that the C# should prefer methods in the `Enumerable` class.

More interestingly, had you written the using block like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

using static System.Linq.Enumerable;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
```

so *outside* the namespace, everything would have worked "correctly" ([IL code generated](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)).

[I'll say that namespace resolution works by level...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16092975/613130) First C# tries all the `using` defined in the innermost level of `namespace`, if there is no one that is good enough then it goes up a level of `namespace`. If there are multiple candidates **in the same level** it takes the best match. In the example without the `using static` and the example I gave where the `using` + the `using static` are all top-level, there is a single level, so the C# takes the best candidate. In the two-levels `using` the innermost one is checked, and the `using static Enumerable` is good enough to resolve the `OrderBy` method, so no extra checking is done.

I'll say that this time again, [*SharpLab*](https://sharplab.io/) was the MVP of this response. If you have a question about what the C# compiler does under the hood, *SharpLab* can give you the response (technically you could use [*ildasm.exe*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) or [*ILSpy*](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), but *SharpLab* is very immediate because it is a web site, and you can interactively change the source code). The SVP (second valuable player) (for me) was *WinMerge*, that I used to compare the IL assemblies

**Answer to the comment**

The [C# 6.0 draft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#using-namespace-directives) page says

> The namespace_name referenced by a using_namespace_directive is resolved in the same way as the namespace_or_type_name referenced by a using_alias_directive. Thus, using_namespace_directives in the same compilation unit or namespace body do not affect each other and can be written in any order.

and then

> Ambiguities between multiple using_namespace_directives and using_static_directives are discussed in Using namespace directives.

so the first rule is applied even to `using static`. This explains why the third example (mine) is equivalent to the no-`using static`.

About why `ParallelEnumerable.OrderedBy()` is better than `Enumerable.OrderBy()` when both of them are checked by the C# compiler, it is simple:

The `AsParallel()` returns a `ParallelQuery<TSource>` (that implements `IEnumerable<TSource>`)

The `ParallelEnumerable.OrderedBy()` signature:

```
public static OrderedParallelQuery<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this ParallelQuery<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

The `Enumerable.OrderedBy()` signature:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

The first one accepts a `ParallelQuery<TSource>`, that is the exact same type returned by `AsParallel()`, no "downcast" necessary.

Comment: Is it fair to boil this down and say this is by design then?  I see nothing in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) about how the compiler picks extension methods where there's more than one that fits the bill.  Your answer makes sense to me, just would love to see where in the C# spec or documentation this is made clear.

Comment: @Zer0 Try [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/overload-resolution)

Comment: @Zer0 expanded the response... check if it is clear

Comment: Crystal clear.  Thanks for expanding.  Very useful for those like me that avoid extension methods (for performance reasons that are insignificant 99.9% of the time).

Comment: @Zer0 What would be the performance downsides of extension methods per se? Or do you mean specifically the LINQ ones?