# Where are the using statements/directives in .NET 6 and above

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I got up and running with Visual Studio 2022 Preview for a couple of days now.

Got the first shock, there is no Startup.cs. Thats ok, a bit of reading, I know Startup is removed.

Today got another slap. I see no using statements. Here it is.

I just created a brand new .NET 6 web app and as I hover over the WebApplication class, I realized it stays in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder namespace. And the generated Program.cs class looks like this.

[image: Program.cs class in ASP.NET core 6 Web app]

So where is the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;` statement?

Whats the magic? Why is .net  becoming mystical by the day?

The full Program.cs file is as follows.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Is there `global using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;` somewhere in your application? Otherwise it would seem like [this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/implicit-namespaces) seems to add an assortment of global usings to your application which are unknowable unless you dig around in your obj folder. Fun!

Comment: `using` *directive*. `using` statements are those which appear as statements in bodies and control Disposal. And if you use the right phrase and go the the documentation for [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) you'd have seen this new behaviour explained.

Comment: @Nathan Cooper, No I don't

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes its using directive.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

C# 10.0 introduces a new feature called [global using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/globalusingdirective) ([`global using <fully-qualified-namespace>;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier)) which allows to specify namespaces to be implicitly imported in all files in the compilation. [.NET 6 RC1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/implicit-namespaces-rc1#new-behavior) has this feature enabled by default in new project templates (see the `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` property in your .csproj).

For `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` [next namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives) should be implicitly imported (plus the ones from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`):

- System.Net.Http.Json
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

**UPD**

To address your questions in the comment:

At the moment of writing the generated file containing default imports will be inside the `obj` folder named something like `ProjectName.GlobalUsings.g.cs`.

To modify default imports you can add [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#using) element to your `.csproj` file. Based on exposed attributes it allows several actions including addition and removal:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="SomeFullyQualifiedNamespace"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

For just addition you can simply prefix your `using` directive with `global` modifier in any file (or create a separate one just for this):

```
global using SomeFullyQualifiedNamespace;
```

Comment: Hi @Guru Stron, Thanks. Yes indeed there is a tag in <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings> in my WebApplication1.csproj file. 
So now, is there a file for this, located globally as I install .net 6 Sdk? If yes, where is the location? Can I customize that, that is, can I add some using directives that I feel I use regularly as a developer?

Comment: @VivekDev the generated file containing default imports will be inside the `obj` folder named something like `ProjectName.GlobalUsings.g.cs`. As for adding your global directives - you can just use `global` modifier on `using` directive in any file (or create separate one for global usings) or add `<Using Include="SomeFullyQualifiedNamespace" />` to your .csproj.

Comment: Related question [Should using directives be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can still add your own using directives at the top of Program.cs. I am aware that I am not showing you all my code, but I was able to build and run something that looks like this:

```
using MvcPrototype1.DataAccess;
using MvcPrototype1.DataAccess.Interfaces;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAddressRepository, AddressRepository>();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

var app = builder.Build();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

- In .net 6.0 you don't need to add some namespaces, because they are excited by default.
- For example:- 
   [image: just hello world example]
- Here we don't have to use the namespace because it's exist by default.
- So where to find it? and know all the namespaces that were installed by default in my project.
- Just go to .csproj project files and you will find enable
  and that's it.
- So by default :-
- if your applications is a console app this packages installed by default:-
  1 - System 
  2 - System.Collections.Generic
  3 - System.IO
  4 - System.Linq
  5 - System.Net.Http
  6 - System.Threading
  7 - System.Threading.Tasks
- if your applications is a web app this packages installed by default:-
  1 - System.Net.Http.Json 
  2 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
  3 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
  4 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
  5 - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
  6 - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
  7 - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  8 - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
  9 - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Comment: Where did you get this list from? Where can I find that on my machine? Can I customize that list?

Comment: 1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style-in-visual-studio

Comment: 2 - https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/

Comment: 3 - https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/?series

Comment: How do I add additional ones?