# Entity Framework Core 6.03 .ToList() not available

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on my first .NET 6 project and I'm using EF to run an inline query and creating a list of objects. However, I don't have .ToList() as an option; I only have .ToListAsync(). From doing a little research is looks like .ToList should still be available so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

This is what I have installed:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.21.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I see no reference to Linq, is that normal?

Comment: Thanks. That pointed me to what looks to have been the issue. I don't think you need Linq reference the packages file but I added "using System.Linq;" to the top of my DataManger page and it looks like I have ToList now. I've had that before and forgot about it. Too bad it doesn't show up as one of the suggestions in VS as how to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the corresponding file.

`ToListAsync` is an extension method for `IQueryable` coming from [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync?view=efcore-6.0) namespace while `ToList` is a framework build in method from [`System.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0).

Another option is to set [`ImplicitUsings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings) to `enable` in the .csproj file to leverage automatic import for default namespaces based on the type of project SDK (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738921/where-are-the-using-statements-directives-in-net-6/69739444#69739444) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives)):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
   ...
   <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
   ... 
</PropertyGroup>
```