# Where and how to include Using directives in C# and .NET6?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, omnisharp

I am programming C# in Visual Studio Code with .NET 6. In .NET 6, an explicit main method is no longer necessary. Does anyone know how and where to include using directives like using `System.Diagnostics`?

This is what my program currently looks like:

```
await MeakeBreakfastAsync();

async Task MakeBreakfastAsync(){
    ...
}

static async Task<string> MakeCoffeAsync() {
    ...
}

static async Task<string> MakeToastAsync() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's not about "explicit main method" per se but about [global using directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738921/where-are-the-using-statements-directives-in-net-6/69739444#69739444) and build in imports for different project types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still can place the usings on top like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
await Task.Delay(1000);
List<int> _ = new();
```

See [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) for more details, especially on how to use `<ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>`.