# Is it possible to write a extension for a typeparameter?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I would like to convert this method

```
public static List<T> GetAllEnumValues<T>() where T : Enum
{
  return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

into a extension.

So that i can use it like this
`Countries.GetAllEnumValues();`
instead of this
`GenericMethods.GetAllEnumValues<Countries>()`

Is there a way to create an extension without passing an instance of the type to be extended?

I'd imagine something like this...

```
public static List<T> GetAllEnumValues<this T>() where T : Enum //not compiling for obvious reasons
{
  return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you should use `Enum.GetValues<T>().ToList()` instead of `Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList()`

Comment: @AluanHaddad: good point, but the method needs a `struct, Enum` constraint then.

Comment: @AluanHaddad  Thanks for the tip. 
Is there any advantage on using GetValues with an type parameter?
Also: I don't quite understand why the `struct` constraint is necessary, but thats quite another topic :)

Comment: @HWS-SLS it's an older API that predates the `Enum` type constraint. At the time constraining to a value type (`struct`) was the closest they could get linguistically. The advantages of the type parameter include fewer casts, type safety, fewer operations, and more readable code. Read about the [Enum constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints) at MSDN.

Comment: Also you should cache the list as it won't change at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

But you can [import static members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier):

```
using static GenericMethods;

GetAllEnumValues<Countries>();
```

Also you can do it [globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739444/2501279). For example in some other file like `GlobalImports.cs`:

```
global using static SomeNamespace.GenericMethods;
```

Or via .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="SomeNamespace.GenericMethods" Static="True"/>
</ItemGroup>
```